# does precum and sperm release without ejaculation require kaffarah and does it invalidate fast

Tags: ramadan

i am 15 year old muslim male who often masturabtes,however, during ramadan i have tried to abstain from this as much as possible. it has been hard to break my addiction and a couple days ago i was aroused and rubbing my penis. i did not have any intention to ejaculate and orgasm however some precum and sperm was released. i panicked as i thought this broke my fast so i orgasmed after this to release the desire completely. Afterwards i did research and from the best of my knowledge i have to either fast 60 continuous days or pay for the meals of 60 people. my question is that did the initial release of sperm and precum invalidate my fast ( i know the orgasm afterwards did for sure astagifirullah ) and since if was not property educated does it still require for me to pay kaffarah if fast 60 continuous days or by allahs mercy am i pardoned

Answer (score -1):

This is a misconception If you have masturbated or eat or drink purposely you have to make up for the days if you have SEXUAL INTERCOURSE then you have to fast for 2 consecutive months I hope you answers your questions repent to Allah ask for forgiveness and Allah Insha’Allah will forgive you.